# Set folders permissions with a foreach using a csv

Tags: powershell

Based in a csv file like this i create this users and his folder:

```
user,password,name
fcuadrado,P@assword,Paco Cuadrado
rita,1234@ASIR,Rita la cantaora
ccoton,Asir1234,Carmelo Conton
```

i create the users in localhost:

```
foreach ($users in (Import-Csv .\usuarios.csv)){
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString  "$users.password" -AsPlainText -Force
New-LocalUser -Name $users.user-Password $securepassword-FullName $users.name
}
```

And the folders:

```
foreach ($users in (Import-Csv .\users.csv)){
New-Item -Name $users.user-Path C:\users-ItemType Directory
}
```

I was trying this but the loop cant cath the user from the csv

```
 foreach ($users in (Import-Csv .\users.csv)){
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path c:\users\$($users.user)
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
    $acl.Access | ForEach-Object { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) | Out-Null }
    $ace = New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ($($users.user), "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
    Set-Acl -Path "c:\users\$($users.user)" -AclObject $acl
    }
```

I want to set the permissions with the foreach that i used to create the folders and users.
once the users problem is fixed, it does not loop me for each user and gives the permissions of all folders to a user instead of each user with a folder name as its user

```
Get-Acl -Path c:\usuarios\fcuadrado
```

This give me the permissions to ccoton.

Comment: one time the path is: .\users.csv and 2 times: .\usuarios.csv - is this right?

Comment: sorry the original script was in spanish. I have translated it for better understanding

Comment: and $users.user returns nothing?

Comment: i update the request with the powershell error

Comment: looks like you need to use `$acl = Get-Acl -Path "c:\users\$($users.user)"`, and then the same quoting method in the `set-acl` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why use multiple foreach loops anyway and not simply do all inside one foreach loop?

```
foreach ($user in (Import-Csv .\users.csv)) {
    $account = $user.user  # just for convenience
    $securepassword = $user.password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    New-LocalUser -Name $account -Password $securepassword -FullName $user.name

    # create the path for the userfolder and store in a variable for re-use
    $userFolder = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Users' -ChildPath $account
    $null = New-Item -Path $userFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $userFolder
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
    $acl.Access | ForEach-Object { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) | Out-Null }
    $ace = [System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($account, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $userFolder 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems you need to look at.
The first one is your CSV file. In the example you are using a comma as a delimiter.
Depending on the culture your PS is running on, the delimiter could be different. So explicitly declare it using the **-Delimiter** parameter:

```
$userData = Import-Csv -Path '.\usuarios.csv' -Delimiter ','
```

After that, check if **$userData** is indeed a PSObject or an array of, so you can call the properties directly.

Second problem is with your parameter declaration at **New-LocalUser**.
Object properties cannot be accessed inside a string without isolation.
This is wrong:

```
New-LocalUser -Name "$user.User" -Password $secpass -FullName "$user.Name"
```

This works:

```
New-LocalUser -Name $user.User -Password $secpass -FullName $user.Name

# Alternatively
New-LocalUser -Name "$($user.User)" -Password $secpass -FullName "$($user.Name)"
```

Comment: There is no cultural difference with the default [`Import-Csv -Delimiter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv#parameters) (**Comma** Seperated Values). The default is just a comma (`,`).

Comment: It is already solved, but now I have a problem with the foreach loop in the acls